# Ошибка 0xC0000005 с++

Tags: c++

Код:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
#define fn(i,n) for(int i=0; i< int(n); i++)
const int   INF=1e9+1;
double Pi=3.14159265359;
#define F first
#define S second
#define all(a) a.begin(),a.end()
typedef long long ll;


int main(){
    ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);
    cout.tie(0);

    ifstream fin("input.txt");
    ofstream fout("output.txt");
    int n,m;
    fin>>n>>m;
    vector<int> a(n),b(m);
    fn(i,n)fin>>a[i];
    fn(i,m)fin>>b[i];
    vector<int> ans;
    bool last;
    int i=a.size()-1,j=b.size()-1;
    while(!(i==j && i==-1)){
        bool tp1=((i%2==1 || i==-1)?0:1);
        bool tp2=((j%2==1 || j==-1)?0:1);
        bool tp=(tp1!=tp2?1:0);
        int mn;
        if(i>=0 && j>=0)
            mn=min(a[i],b[j]);
        else mn=(i!=-1?a[i]:b[j]);
        if((i==a.size()-1 && j==b.size()-1) || tp!=last)
            ans.push_back(mn);
        else
            ans[ans.size()-1]+=mn;
        if(mn==a[i])i--;
        else a[i]-=mn;
        if(mn==b[j])j--;
        else b[j]-=mn;
        last=tp;
    }
    if(last==false)
        ans.resize(ans.size()-1);
    reverse(all(ans));
    fn(z,ans.size()){
        if(z==ans.size()-1)
            fout<<ans[z];
        else
            fout<<ans[z]<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

При вводе теста:

```
3 4
12550 68316 99658
79647 97673 35501 43437
```

В файл *input.txt* программа выдает ошибку *0xC0000005* на стадии удаления вектора.

Как избавиться от данной ошибки?

Comment: Mamma mia! Переболейте скорее этой детской болезнью крутизны в программизме и перестаньте использовать `#define` - ничего, кроме запутывания при чтении программы они не дают! Лучше бы приучились текст комментировать - а то что вы тут делаете и зачем, надо просто раскапывать...

Comment: Трассируйте. Найдите строку где произошёл сбой.

Comment: @Harry это явно олимпиадное программирование, а не продакшн, там такие дефайны обычное дело, чекеру не нужны комментарии и кроме автора кода навряд ли его кто-то будет эту программу читать

Comment: @BeaverFeller Как видите, помимо чекера этот код воткнут нам :) Ладно комментарии, но дефайны эти нафига? Что, экономия на скорости набора? Не верю.

Comment: @Harry ну когда топовые олимпиадники успевают решить 3 задачи контеста за первые 7 минут (я вообще не понимаю как они это так быстро делают), то наверное все же подобные штуки помогают сократить время самого кодинга

Comment: @BeaverFeller Позвольте не поверить, что мы имеем дело именно с таким программистом. Не стал бы он спрашивать у нас совета, сам бы нашел проблему...

Comment: @Beaver Feller: Человек, сознательно старающийся "сократить время кодинга", не будет писать `bool tp=(tp1!=tp2?1:0);`, `ans[ans.size()-1]+=mn;`, `if(last==false)` или `ans.resize(ans.size()-1)`.

Comment: @AnT ну да, это выглядит ещё хуже дефайнов :). А так, я не про автора речь веду, а про то, что в олимпиадном программировании нет код стайла и комментов, каждый кодит кто как хочет :). Но, конечно, заливать такой код stackoverflow не очень красиво со стороны автора

Comment: Что насчет дефайнов-мне так удобней. А тернарный оператор для краткости. Принял к сведению, буду избавляться от вредной привычки.

Answer (score 3):

Воткнем в ваш код немного `assert`'ов и обнаружим тут же выход за пределы диапазона:

```
    if(mn==a[i])i--;
    else {
        assert(i < a.size());
        a[i]-=mn;
    }
```

А почему и как это исправить - это вы уж в своем C00l-коде разберитесь самостоятельно. Понимать, что именно он делает, только по вашему исходнику (в котором уже найдена как минимум одна ошибка), без описания поставленной задачи - увольте, телепатия сегодня с утра по погодным условиям не работает... :)